# bar graph shows only one bar

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart

why does this bar graph only shows one bar instead of showing them all ? I keep changing the 3rd parameter but when I increase it too much, it just displays one thick bar instead of many small ones.

```
plt.bar(list(range(300)),list(range(300)) ,5)
```

Comment: When you say one bar, is it shaped like a rectangle? Or is it shaped more like a triangle/trapezoid?

Comment: rectangle shaped

Comment: That really is odd then, when I try `plt.bar(list(range(300)),list(range(300)) ,5)` I get a triangle or trapezoid, which is what you expect from 300 thick bars being drawn over each other.

Answer (score 1):

It's just your width is too large and hence you see it clotted. Take this for example

```
plt.bar(list(range(5)),list(range(5, 10)),0.2)
```

Here we are saying that we want to have `x value as [0,1,2,3,4]` and the height of each value at x as `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and the total width of `0.2` (so say for x[0] the bar starts from -0.1 and end at 0.1 and has a height of 5.). From that in your case, you are making `300` bars and each with a single increase in size and a width of 5 which is not possible as there aren't possible as there are no 5 steps between 0,1 and in fact not in the whole [0,300]. To get a better understanding plot this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.bar(list(range(300)),list(range(300)),0.2)
```

It will get more and more clear as you increase the `figsize` or decrease the `range()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the code below, you will see that it is not showing one huge bar, but ALL of the bars super close together. Scale the list range up to 300 with the default size parameters of the chart and it looks like one giant bar. Try changing the 3rd parameter to a float less than 1 and see if that helps what you are trying to plot.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.bar(list(range(20)),list(range(20)), 5)
plt.show()
```